# how to use hasMany association in index.ctp

Tags: cakephp

I have 3 database table for Image and Comment and Post...

I want's to load multiple image for every post and show it in a carousel slideshow...

So add the hasMany association in the post model for image model..

> post model :

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Image' => array(
        'className' => 'Image',
        'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
    )
);
```

and use the saveAll method and `array('deep' => true)` for saving to all table.

but when i want's to load associated data in the index of post did not work only work's in the view of every post but i want to show the slideshow for every post in the index.

when i change the hasMany to hasOne the associated work correctly in the index..

what can i do...

Comment: please share your controller's code of index function

Comment: In your index method try: $this -> Post -> recursive = 1;

Comment: $this -> Post -> recursive = 1; work exactly right

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you are describeing, the `Post` model should have a `hasMany` relation to the `Image` model.

Because the this relation will result in an array structure when loading the information, you have to access it with a loop or something similar. It it hard to propose a more precise soloution unless you post your controller and view.